# MapActivity: accessing MapController and LocationManager from OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, mapactivity

I am trying to implement a map with a button that will animate back to the user's current position.
I am having a hard time trying to find a way to access my MapController from inside the OnClickListener.

I have searched through SO but haven't found a proper answer to my problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener
{
    private LimitedZoomMapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private Gallery gallery;
    private ImageButton centerPositionButton;
    // [...]



 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.mapView = (LimitedZoomMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        this.mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // [...]
        this.centerPositionButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.centerposbutton);
    this.centerPositionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Access MapController and LocationManager from here 
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot set `MapController` and `LocationMager` to final as they are initialized in `onCreate`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to make them final? or want to access them in OnClick? your code seems worked for me.

Comment: @ChintanRathod the `final` usage was referring to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147120/accessing-variables-from-onclicklistener

Comment: @Pratik which keyword? setting those to public does not allow me to access them from the `onClickListener` using `this.mapView`

Comment: @rxdazn, I know when you have declared any object in your method, it must be final. As you have declared your objects out of method, there is no need to make them final. My Question is Why do you want to make them final? If you want, just remove global declaration and put in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @rxdazn read this link when should use "this keyword". http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword In your code no need to write "this keyword".remove it.

Comment: You should really take a look at maps v2 : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: @ddewaele my project is almost done, this is the only feature missing actually. Plus I have to use maps v1.

Comment: Like people mentioned, with the code above you can call mapController and locationManager in the onClick. Just don't prefix it with "this."

Comment: @ddewaele oh yeah it does work now. Just post an answer rather than a comment and I will gladly mark is as accepted.

Comment: That honour should goto @Pratik

Comment: @ddewaele thanks for that..it's OK dude he has solved his problem that's great..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    used map v2


        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            Cursor c = adp.getaddress(surname);// get address from the database
            c.moveToFirst();
            adderess = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3));// get
                                                                                    // address
                                                                                    // in
                                                                                    // string
                                                                                    // for
                                                                                    // used
                                                                                    // location
                                                                                    // for
                                                                                    // the
                                                                                    // map

            /* get latitude and longitude from the adderress */

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(adderess, 5);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                    Double lat = (double) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude());
                    Double lon = (double) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude());

                    Log.d("lat-long", "" + lat + "......." + lon);
                    final LatLng user = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                    /*used marker for show the location */
                    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(user)
                            .title(adderess)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
                    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(user, 15));

                    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



   <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```